# Time-delayed saving of the composition of a page with Opera/Chrome browser extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opera, content-script

I'm trying to create a browser extension for Opera (derived from Chrome) that does the following.

It's supposed to store the result of displaying a page returned by google translator when opening urls into a customizable tab folder, so exactly what I get when I press Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+S, but just from a list of pairs of URL and desired file name.

Either it doesn't happen at all, or the untranslated page comes back with HTML gibberish.

Example (DE for Thursday): `https://programtv-onet-pl.translate.goog/program-tv/4fun-tv-269?dzien=0&_x_tr_sl=pl&_x_tr_tl=de&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp`

Example (EN for Friday): `https://programtv-onet-pl.translate.goog/program-tv/4fun-tv-269?dzien=1&_x_tr_sl=pl&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp`

The dzien parameter specifies the offset in relation to GMT (server time 0=today and before 1 a.m. the following day, 1=tomorrow from 1 a.m. etc.)

If you press Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+S you get the file `"4FUN.TV - Program TV.html"` without intervention (this takes up to a minute depending on the free RAM), but it works manually.

In order to further process the text with Python, or sed, lex and yacc, it must be in German (see example1 for today) or English (see example 2 for tomorrow) and if possible without Javascript and HTML tags - just as it is generated with Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+S.

The parameter _x_tr_sl sets the source language (pl) and the _x_tr_tl sets the target language (de) or (en) and _x_tr_hl=de set the homeland.

The approach would be to call up the page, wait 15s for the google translator to run through and then simulate a user input that simulates Ctrl+A and Ctrl+S, whereby the entry in the file dialog would still have to be changed, the data from a json file come - that's the plan. Then the next URL with a matching file name, possibly with an increment of the dzien parameter using a for loop.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "description": "example born again!",
  "version": "0.1.6",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://programtv-onet-pl.translate.goog/*"],
        "css": ["content-script.css"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],        
  "options_page": "options.html",  
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "backgound.js"
  }, 
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/example-logo-16.png",
      "32": "/images/example-logo-32.png",
      "48": "/images/example-logo-48.png",
      "128": "/images/example-logo-128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/example-logo-16.png",
    "32": "/images/example-logo-32.png",
    "48": "/images/example-logo-48.png",
    "128": "/images/example-logo-128.png"
  }
}
```

**The main problem is the english or german webseite from google translator**

If this solved can python or awk+sed+lex+yacc run over it and replace header, sidebar, footer, unwanted links and strip/replace too long lines to fit into 3-col DIN-A4 landscape and it should look like below without double entries - the right size for a small message, but this may build later. Timezones and daytimes of homelans may applied later. After all a pdf in the right language, right timezone and date is the final result.

4FunTV.de.txt for German Viewers for Thursday 2022-08-04 (dzien=0 and _x_tr_tl=de)

```
4FUN.TV-Programm Donnerstag 04.08.2022

03:00 Die meiste Musik in der Nacht
05:00 Karaoke auf 4FUN.TV
07:00 energiegeladene Musik zum Aufwachen
09:00 Die 20 beliebtesten Hits der Woche aus den Charts
11:00 Geliehene Noten
12:00 Die meiste Musik für den Sommer
13:00 Heißer Pop
14:00 Zuschauer entscheiden über die Reihenfolge der Songs
15:00 die besten aktuellen Hits und gewürzt mit Humor
18:00 Heiß & frisch
20:00 Kommentare und Grüße von Zuschauern
21:00 Heißer Pop
22:00 Die meiste Musik für den Sommer
00:00 Karaoke auf 4FUN.TV
03:00 Die meiste Musik in der Nacht
```

4FunTV.en.txt for englisch Viewers for Friday 2022-08-05 (dzien=1 and _x_tr_tl=en)

```
4FUN.TV program Friday 2022-08-05

03:00 am Most music at night
05:00 am Karaoke on 4FUN.TV
07:00 am 4FUN wakes people up
09:00 am The most music for the summer
11:00 am The most absurd news of the week
12:00 pm The most music for the summer
01:00 pm Hot Pop
02:00 pm viewers decide about the order of the songs broadcast
03:00 pm the best current hits and seasoned with a pinch of humor
05:00 pm latest information on the world of cinema
06:00 pm Hot & Fresh
08:00 pm comments and greetings from viewers
09:00 pm best dance songs in the evening time
01:00 am Karaoke on 4FUN.TV
03:00 am Most music at night
```

### Supplement from 08/12/2022

In the meantime, I have compared the outputs that you receive in manual operation if you press

1. Ctrl+A to select everything in the page and then press Ctrl+S to save everything and then
2. the output that comes from going through the Windows clipboard and then pasting into a blank page of a plain text editor (later a string-buffer) like Scintilla, so (2) Ctrl+A to select everything, then Ctrl+C for that copy to the clipboard, then click in the empty page at the top left and then press Ctrl+S to save.

Voila, there's a very significant, purposeful difference though.

While in variant (1) the HTML tags are still there, which makes the structure of the parser considerably more difficult, they are no longer in variant (2) and that's exactly what I want, just not manually, but via browser extension.

This makes it clear that only variant (2) is effective and independent of the design of the website, which considerably simplifies the structure of the parser.

In the meantime I have read that what I have to do for variant (2) belongs in the backup script, while the further processing, then removing the remaining, superfluous remainder, such as the explanation of the channel number, belongs in the content script and the default settings so far those not in the database belong on the options page.

The script just have to ask the server to run the parser for the complex control logic in between, which in turn generates the final page, which then saves again according to variant (2), which results in what I want as the essence for further processing, in order to create the LaTeX-table with the content, which is then fetched via FTP, run through Latex via Makefile and then the final PDF is written back with FTP to provide the download for the users.

This means that the end product is ready by cron job. The rest of the toolchain is familiar technology to me.

I have only problems with the partially unclear, contradictory and incomplete documentation of the browser extensions, similar to Mozilla Thunderbird where there is a lot of old crap between the current status and if you use it just doesn't work.

Of course I would open source some of the browser functionality so that it can be reviewed and improved. That's clear and the rest is provided as a ready-to-use with linkable API with a description, because I don't want to bother with GUI optimization as well - it has to be functional and secure, but I don't want to have to do everything myself with themes and similar gimmicks, because I don't need it, but users might find it chic and nice to have one.

The last refinement would be to set the language of the Google translator in the first line through the browser depending on the tv and radio channels and to adjust the source and target URL for the run of the next channel, whose URL is in the database as well as the URLs of the channel logos that stored in a read-only FTP directory structure of the server and later inserted into the PDF when formatting via LaTeX.

That would be the toolchain - I can handle that, but I can't yet get the commands to save the page for the first step correctly, nor can I get the simulated user commands to switch the Google translator correctly, because I'm not familiar with the browser extension and still have to learn more.

The rest is easy for me to do in Makefile with bash, C, PHP or Python, because that is not so time-critical, even if there could be well over 100 channels, because it only has to be run through once a day and then some rework of an hour is also OK, but not having to do everything manually, but automated, so that the effort does not get out of hand when adding more channels and then you have to consider that the effort would increase again with each target language of the program preview and I can do that don't have to do it full-time with a lot of people - the program has to do that on its own.